# Why does my logo doesn't show in 'forgot password' page in laravel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the basic laravel authentication using

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I am using twitter bootstrap for the front-end.

I have put up an image for my brand name, and it shows perfectly in all the other pages, but when I am trying to use the option for 'forgot password', the page doesn't show my logo, rather it just shows the alt text.

Can you please tell me, how to resolve this issue?

Thank You

Comment: It can be cause of absolute/relative path

Comment: You must provide more information to help you. Which URL is the browser trying to request when it can't load the image? What did you code?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the auth templates located at resources/views/auth and make sure the layout file extended is the right one.

Check at the top:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

And make sure that file exists at resources/views/layouts